# $.each return [object Object] while .map() do it correctly

Tags: jquery, each

I have some code:

```
$.getJSON(url, results => {

                    $('.search-output').html(`
                    <div class = "general">      
                   ${results.generalinfo.map( (item, index) => {      
                             return     `<h1>${item.title}</h1>`
                            })}
                        </div>

                    <div class = "profiles">

                     ${$.each(results.profiles, function(index, item) {

                     return     `<h1>${item.title}</h1>`


                     })} 
                    </div> `)
                })
```

With `.map()` function I can get all I want, but `$.each()` return `[object Object]`. What I tried in `$.each` function: `JSON.stringify`, `.join()` at the end - nothing changed. What is the difference between this functions and how I can use `$.each()` in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: We don't have the structure of your data `results`; and you don't even seem to be using the variable `results` at all. For that reason, your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're setting the data on the tr and then filling it with your html, but still concatinating an object, which converts it to a string... aka

"[object Object]"
Not exactly sure what you're after but you might try changing this...

html += tr.data('trackinfo',value).html(tr_data);
To this...

html += tr.data('trackinfo',value).html(tr_data).html();